# Computing distances from points to a line in vector form efficiently

Tags: python, numpy

Computing the [distance of a point to a line in vector form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Vector_formulation) is trivial.

However, I implemented it the following way, which is extremely slow:

```
def compute_point_distance_to_line(point):
    dist = np.linalg.norm((a - point) - np.vdot((a - point), n) * n)
    return dist
np.apply_along_axis(compute_point_distance_to_line, 1, xyz)
```

I used the notation from wikipedia, xyz shape is (2521909, 3), shape of a, n and point is consequently (3,)

I tried it the following way:

```
def compute_point_distance_to_line2(points):
    _a = np.tile(a, (points.shape[0], 1))
    _n = np.tile(n, (points.shape[0], 1))
    _n_t = np.ascontiguousarray(np.swapaxes(_n, 0, 1))

    diffs = _a - points
    vdots_scaled = np.dot(diffs, _n_t) * n
    diffs = diffs - vdots_scaled

    return np.linalg.norm(diffs, axis=1)
```

Unfortunately, for me this results in a Memory Error when computing the dot product.

Are there any faster ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can vectorize this with something like:

```
temp = np.subtract(a, xyz)  # so we only have to compute this once
dist = np.linalg.norm(np.subtract(temp, np.multiply(np.dot(temp, n)[:, None], n)),
                      axis=-1)
# 220 ms ± 6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Compared with timing for your first code example above:

```
# 30 s ± 1.89 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

It's giving me the same result as your first code example (checked with `np.array_equal()`), and it is a couple of orders of magnitude faster.

---

#### Explanation

The trick is getting the `np.multiply()` call to work correctly by adding an extra axis to the result of `np.dot()`, which I do with the `[:, None]` slice after `np.dot()`. Basically `None` used in numpy slices is a shortcut for adding an axis, so the result of `np.dot()` for you should have shape `(2521909,)`, and after the brackets with `None`, it will have shape `(2521909, 1)`. The result of `np.multiply()` (and `temp`) will then have shape `(2521909, 3)`, and we take the norm along the last axis to get the 3-dimensional distance from the line to each of your 2521909 points.

Comment: Yes! This is really fast. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In general, try not to use operations like `tile` when you can use broadcasting instead, especially when speed/memory is an issue.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html

With a little algebra you can write this as a single matrix vector product, followed by the norm.  This may help you avoid temporary variables and save on memory.

Here is a working example.  Note that in this example all the 3D vectors are column vectors so `p` is 3x1000 instead of 1000x3.  You will have to transpose your `p` to plug it into this example.

```
import numpy as np
# define an example line with unit n
a = np.array([1,2,3])
n = np.array([4,5,6])
norm2n = np.sum(n**2)
n = n/np.sqrt(norm2n)
# get some point data p
p = np.random.randn(3,1000)
# form the projection matrix (see use of None in broadcasting at link above)
P = np.eye(3) - n[:,None]*n[None,:]
# perform the projection using matrix multiplication    
projected = P.dot(a[:,None]-p)
# get the distance
dist = np.sqrt(np.sum(projected**2, axis=0))
```